# Выбор модели маршрутизатора с поддержкой OpenVPN клиента

Tags: сервер, железо, vpn, openvpn, маршрутизатор

Нужна помощь в выборе модели маршрутизатора с поддержкой OpenVPN клиента.

Основные требования OpenVPN клиента:

- Поддержка AES-256-CBC
- Поддержка SHA512
- Поддержка TCP (есть маршрутизаторы с поддержкой только UDP)

Что было найдено и отвергнуто: DD-WRT, не понравилась.
Какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: n.b.: *dd-wrt* — это настолько **не** «модель маршрутизатора», что дальше просто некуда.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не утрируйте, мне просто не нравится сама DD-WRT (которая устанавливается на множество маршрутизаторов).

Comment: @Align - исполнение вам нужно какое? В стойку 19", в виде коробочки на стену, в виде ящика на стол?

Comment: @gbg, исполнение не важно, подойдет любое, лучше несколько вариантов.

Comment: @Align пробуйте OpenWRT

Comment: @gbg, спасибо, попробую. А есть ли что-то заводское, наподобии RouterOS от микротик? Просто не очень доверяю DD-WRT и его аналогам. В них постоянно находят баги и уязвимости, а фиксят их не очень быстро. Цель маршрутизатора - обеспечение безопасности в первую очередь.

Comment: @Align - в таком случае, берите персоналку, ставьте на нее Linux SuSe Tumbleweed или другой rolling-release и будете использовать наисвежайшие релизы.

Comment: @gbg, так использовать ПК под данные задачи - это костыльно. Вообще OpenWRT подходит, возьму скорее всего поддерживаемый микротик, поставлю OpenWRT, а когда саппорт добавит SHA512 - поставлю RouterOS.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42241/discussion-between-gbg-and-align).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Из требований к маршрутизатору обычно указывают количество портов, пропускную способность, тип интерфейсов (Ethernet / SFP / SFP+ / Wi-Fi 2 / wi-Fi 5), исполнение (в стойку 19", в виде коробочки на стену, в виде ящика на стол)
2. OpenVPN лучше себя чувствует, когда работает по UDP.
3. Можно взять практически любой ширпотребный роутер и поставить в него OpenWRT.
4. Можно взять практически любой компьютер или одноплатник (если куча портов не нужна), и поставить на него тот же OpenWrt или pfSense.
5. Наконец, есть целая толпа микротиков.

Comment: Бешено плюсую. Также автор вопроса не указал какая производительность ему нужна. Условно роутер, который сможет обеспечить 10мбит по впн, и роутер, который сможет 100, могут по цене отличаться на порядки

Comment: Более того - не понимаю этой зацикленности на openvpn. Для домашнего использования оптимум l2tp (он есть везде, даже на айфон с андроид). Для промышленного - IPsec. Чтобы прятать трафик под видом https придумали sstp...

Comment: @gecube Лично меня openvpn привлекает tap-интерфейсом. Можно избавиться от хитрой маршрутизации и наделать мостов.

А для ста мегабит - достаточно просто взять обыкновенную персоналку третьей свежести.

Comment: роутер из компьютера - костыльное решение. Специализированные роутеры вроде младших Mikrotik - оптимальное решение по многим параметрам (например, надежность, гарантия работы программной части, цена стартовая и совокупная стоимость владения, возможность запитать роутеры от и убрать, например, под потолок - с персоналкой так не получится и т.д.)

Comment: @gbg, по поводу микротиков - все они поголовно не поддерживают SHA512 в клиенте OpenVPN. Я отправил запрос на добавление данного функционала, но саппорт назвал временной интервал в несколько месяцев. Именно поэтому я ищу альтернативу с поддержкой SHA512. Нужен именно машрутизатор, даже с полосой пропускания в 10 мегабит при подключенном клиенте OpenVPN.